# TYPO3 7.4: Get list-elements with title of parent

Tags: menu, typo3, parent

I'm generating a list of the 10 latest created pages. My general page-sorting in the Backend is:

```
root
-- category1
---- article1
---- article2
---- article3
-- category2
---- article4
---- article5
---- article6
```

So the list has to contain the title of the article plus the title of its parent page, the category. I got most of it running but I struggle to output the category-title.

Here's my TS:

```
lib.lastUpdated = COA
lib.lastUpdated {
    10 = HMENU
    10.wrap = <div class="lastupdated">|</div>
    10 {
        special = updated
        special.value = 5
        special.depth = 4
        special.beginAtLevel = 2
        special.mode = starttime
        maxItems = 10

        alternativeSortingField = starttime desc

        1 = TMENU
        1 {
            NO {
                allWrap = <div class="lu-elem">|</div>

                after.cObject = COA
                after.cObject {
                    10 = TEXT
                    10 {
                        field = starttime
                        date = d.m.y
                        noTrimWrap = |&nbsp;<span class="created">|</span><br />|
                    }
                    20 = TEXT
                    20 {
                        field = subtitle
                        wrap = <p class="subtitle">|&nbsp;<p>
                    }

                    30 = RECORDS #this is not working
                    30 {
                        source.field = uid
                        tables = pages
                        conf.pages = TEXT
                        conf.pages.data = leveltitle:0 #displays title of CURRENT page's parent

                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Anybody can help?

Answer (score 0):

To get the title of the parent page:

```
30 = RECORDS
30 {
    source.field = uid
    tables = pages
    conf.pages = RECORD
    conf.pages {
        # select the uid of the parent page of the current page
        source.field = pid
        tables = pages
        dontCheckPid = 1
        # print the header
        conf.pages = TEXT
        conf.pages.field = header
    }
}
```

Comment: Thats the problem: leveltitle only shows the title of the parent **of the page I'm currently on**. But I need the title of each page's parent which is generated in the list. With records I can select the object by UID und use its title / navtitle / crdate and so on. Unfortunately I need its parent's title. Sorry, I'm bad at explaining, I hope you get it somehow :D

Comment: You can use another ``RECORDS`` while rendering the result of the first record. ``conf.pages = RECORDS ...``

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea how I am supposed to do that and what it will be good for. Can you edit your answer and show me how the code should look like? Would be lovely!